# Signing an apk in Android Studio which is already in playstore

Tags: android, apk

I have already signed and released an apk on playstore using Eclipse. Now I have started using Android Studio. Now When i enhance the same app with the same keystore value , and test the apk should'nt it update the same app in the device, it installs a fresh Application. The project is migrated from Eclipse , It has the same package name obviously. It is in debug mode, Should it update the same  app or install a fresh new application during debugging??

Comment: is your new apk is uploaded to playstore??

Comment: no , not yet i am just testing it on my device.

Comment: then don't worry, just uninstall and install. Nothing will happen

Comment: when i publish the app will it overwrite it?

Comment: yes, it will ask user to update, not to install